# Issue with regex slector

Tags: jquery

I have web page with calendar. I have got divs with days. Example.

```
<div id="zabuto_calendar_smu_2020-04-29_day" class="day">29</div>
```

How can i select current date? I have current date in date variable and and need select current date, not all of them. I have 3 dots, because there is a random string.  I have tried:

```
$(".day").filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('id').match('zabuto_calendar_..._' + date + '_day');
}).click();
```

but it does not work. Can sameone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
var match =  $(this).attr('id').match(/zabuto_calendar_smu_(.+)_day/i);
console.log(match[1]);
```

alternatively

```
var match =  str.match(/_([20|19].+)_day/i);
```

Comment: But i have current date in date variable and and need select current date, not all of them

Comment: you mean you want to select it with date variable? then you should use `$("[id^='"+date+"'])` instead of $(".day")

Answer (score 0):

You can use both [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) in combination as follows:

```
$('[id^="zabuto_calendar_"][id$="_' + date '_day"].day').....
```

This will select only one div element, assuming there's one div for each date, and there's not need to use the `.filter()` method.

```js
let date = '2020-04-30';
$('[id^="zabuto_calendar_"][id$="_' + date + '_day"].day').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color:#FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zabuto_calendar_smu_2020-04-29_day" class="day">29</div>
<div id="zabuto_calendar_smu_2020-04-30_day" class="day">30</div>
<div id="zabuto_calendar_smuxx_2020-05-01_day" class="day">03</div>
<div id="zabuto_calendar_smuxy_2020-05-02_day" class="day">02</div>
```